# Adobe InDesign Server examples

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I'm new to Adobe InDesign Server and I'm having a hard time finding a good kitchen sink app. All the examples I got from the SDK seem to partially work.  All I'm trying to do is use a master page from InDesign from the server side and edit certain text fields.  For example placing first and last name in particular text fields.  Does anyone know of a good place to get examples code that shows all the features or how I would approach this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html#idserver Has a lot of resources that is useful when starting out. In particular http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/InDesignServer/ids-solutions.pdf includes a number of code examples for various common operations.

As to your specific example, the typical way to go about it is:
1. Get the page object from the master pages list.
2. Iterate over each text field on the page.
3. Somehow identify the fields, for example by setting the script label in the template document and checking the labels of each text field you iterate through.
4. Set the contents of the text field.

Comment: cs6 version doc. https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/server/ids-solutions.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the official InDesign documentation is partial.

Jongware also hosts the complete reference documentation:
http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason why teh IDS documentation isn't that exhaustive is that dealing with the server version is an extension of the classical indesign use. So the exception of some peculiarities detailed in the ids sdk docs, you will find most of the help with InDesign Scripting guides ;)